# PHP/MYSQL Duplicate Email Address

Tags: php, sql, mysql, database

I am trying to prevent users on a site I'm working on from having duplicate email addresses. This is the method I'm using:

```
function createUser( $emlAd )
{
     $sql = "SELECT FROM Users WHERE email='$emlAd'" ;

     $result = mysql_query( $sql ) ;

     if( mysql_num_rows( $result ) > 0 )
     {
 die( "There is already a user with that email!" ) ;
     }//end if

     //rest of function
}//end createUser
```

This code does not accomplish its task, and the user is still able to create an account with an already used email. The weird thing is that when I change the if condition to:

```
mysql_num_rows( $result ) == 0
```

The user isn't able to create an account with any email address. Why does the code not pass control to the if block when the number of rows is greater than 0?

Comment: Try dumping $sql before executing and see if that gives you a better clue as to why its not finding any results

Comment: Make sure to take a look at `mysql_real_escape_string`. It's something you'll want to get used to using early.

Comment: Have you checked that the query actually suceeded? $result will be boolean FALSE if there was a problem, and the mysql_num_rows call will fail, also returning false, which will get typecast to 0, which lead to a `(0 > 0)` check, and the user gets in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

SELECT * FROM... (note the asterisk after SELECT).. I don't think you are calling any records (except the 1st record in Users) by the way you are running it. I could be wrong but give it a shot anyhow,.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you're never getting a match on email.  So

```
mysql_num_rows( $result ) == 0
```

will always be true.

try

```
echo $sql
```

to make sure your SQL looks right.  You may not be passing $emlAd correctly to createUser()